# I want to sync my one folder and sub folder ,with OneDrive

Tags: android, synchronization, live-sdk, onedrive

I want to sync my folder and sub folder in it, all files with OneDrive SDK, please give me idea , other stuff i will handle.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please share with us what did you do so far

Comment: I didn't do anything for this but i have working application, now i want to add this functionality so i need an idea like,,i will create a service then what to do next?

Comment: If you are looking to see what the API offer checkout https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-api-docs  Around your specific question, there is a view.changes api that will allow for real file synchronization opposed to 'guess'n sync'